# Summer internship with no experience in sub-field

Tags: computer-science, research-undergraduate, data-science

I am graduating in a few months with a BSc in Computer Science. I am applying to summer research internships for Data Science. I have done 2 research internships in the past, both related to NLP.

The institute that I want to apply to, however, does not offer such positions, so I would like to apply for the ML explainability group. The issue is, I do not have any experience in that sub-field, although I am curious to learn more.

Are undergraduate interns expected to have an in-depth knowledge of the topic beforehand? Should I address that in the SOP?

Answer (score 2):

As an undergraduate student, you're at the bottom of the academic food chain. In other words, nobody has any real (academic) expectations of you. You're not going to be an expert, you will need time to become familiar with things, and you will need more supervision than a graduate student or postdoc.

So ...

- Are undergraduate interns expected to have an in-depth knowledge of the topic beforehand? No.
- Should I address that in the SOP? Yes, but don't explain why you don't have in-depth knowledge of the topic. Demonstrate that you are familiar with adjacent fields, and explain why you want to learn this topic.